# php fwrite not writing

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I'm trying to write a nickname from teamspeak to a file.

It goes through all the checks, but when I check the file afterwards, nothing gets written.

```
$file = "test.txt";

$fh = fopen($file, 'w');

if(file_exists($file))
{
    echo "exist";   
}else{
    echo "absent";
}

if(is_writable($file))
{
    echo "writable";
}else {
    echo "cant write";
}

if (false === $fh) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open log file for writing');
}

foreach($Summoners as $su){
 $name = $su["TsNICK"];
 echo $name;

 fwrite($fh, $name);

 echo "Wrote to file";


}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: you are opening the file in a loop , not closing it again opening it in the loop. If I may advise , comment $fh = fopen($file, 'w'); in you rloop

Comment: Take a minute to walk through your code visually. `fopen(...'w')` truncates the file before it writes to it. How many times to you do that in this script?

Comment: Ok, I commented it out. So that only the $fh is before the foreach loop. It still isn't writing.

Comment: Are you sure that `$su['TsNICK']` is defined?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell why your code isn't working, but you should consider rewriting it to this:

```
$file = "test.txt";

if (false === ($fh = fopen($file, 'w'))) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open log file for writing');
}

foreach($Summoners as $su) {
    $name = $su["TsNICK"];
    echo $name;
    fwrite($fh, "$name\n");
}

fclose($fh);
```

If you wish to always append to a file, you would need mode `'a'` instead of `'w'`.